# Visual Studio Using Excessive amount of Ram

Tags: visual-studio, lag

My visual studio is using 90% of the total Ram I have (4 gigs) and it is freezing my visual studio also. Is there any way to make this more efficient and make my visual studio go faster?

It does this when i open a existing project or save a certain file.

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more information about what the likely cause is. No one here has access to your machine to help with such little information and VS does not typically use 4GB of ram.

Comment: Did you use 64 Bit Machine?
3rd Party Plugins aktive? like ReSharper?

Comment: What VS version? What SKU? What OS?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this sporadically with a version of VS2008 I use.  I investigated and found that it was trying to access some shared drives for which it had insufficient privileges, and that seemed to delay the loading of the system.

Also, and maybe not related, when that particular version of VS is loaded and stays loaded for a long time, the compiles get slower and slower. Exiting it and re-loading it makes the compiles go much faster.